# JavaScript - Inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I have 2 class: animal(parent) and dog(the 'child' of animal),
when I create an object of Animal, and try to alert the name of the animal,
I got undefined , and not her real name. Why?
(sorry about the double post )

```
function Animal(name, year){
    alert(name);
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;

    this.age = function (){
        var n = new Date().getFullYear();
        return n - this.year;
    };
}

function Dog(name, year, color, type) {
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
    Animal.call(this, name, year);

    //override method age of animal
    this.age = function (){
        var n = new Date().getFullYear();
        return (n - this.year) * 7;
    };

    Dog.prototype.age();
}

Dog.prototype = new Animal();
```

(This js class named: JsClass.js)

and in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="JsClass.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var p1 = new Animal("rex",2008);
        </script>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

(using Eclipse)

Thank you!

Comment: For reference, you'd typically call the parent constructor before setting your own fields, rather than after.  Shouldn't cause the problem you're seeing, though.

Comment: now I see that if i delete this line:
Dog.prototype = new Animal();

it's alert the animal name. so what's the problem with this line? where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

*when I create an object of Animal, and try to alert the name of the animal, I got undefined , and not her real name*

Your alert function is in the animal constructor function. **You didn't pass anything into that function** when you instantiated it as the prototype of Dog.

**Here's what's happening:**

`Dog.prototype = new Animal();` calls the constructor function without any parameters (hence the undefined alert) and sets the prototype of dog to the Animal instance.

`new Animal("rex", 2008);` calls the constructor again. This time, with a name, so you'll get "rex".

I recommend setting the methods as properties of the prototype. That way, the functions don't get created on every instance. I would change your code to look like this:

```
function Animal(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
};

Animal.prototype.age = function() {
    var n = new Date().getFullYear();
    return n - this.year;
};

function Dog(name, year, color, type) {
    Animal.call(this, name, year);
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
};

// Override method age of animal
Dog.prototype.age = function() {
    var n = new Date().getFullYear();
    return (n - this.year) * 7;
};

Dog.prototype = new Animal();
```

But there's still one problem - you're invoking the Animal constructor *twice*. Once when you set it to be the prototype of Dog, and another when you do `Animal.call()`. One way around this is to use Crockford's [method of inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).

Comment: thanks. but which parameters should I insert into this line:
Dog.prototype = new Animal('wow');
?

Comment: Should just be Dog.prototype = new Animal();

Answer (score 1):

```
function Animal(name , year){
    alert(name);
    this.name = name;
    this.year=year;

    this.age= function (){
        var n= new Date().getFullYear();
        return n-this.year;
    };
}
    function Dog(name , year , color , type) {      
        this.color=color;
        this.type=type;
        Animal.call(this, name,year);

        //override method age of animal
        this.age= function (){
            var n= new Date().getFullYear();
            return (n-this.year)*7;
        };

        Dog.prototype.age();
    }

// you invoke Animal as constructor. but you did not pass any argument to it . so name any year will be undefined in Animal() so alert will show undefined
    Dog.prototype = new Animal();

//  here is the normal invoke so alert will show rex
var p1 = new Animal("rex",2008);
```

your code will invoke Animal twice, the first invoke alert undefined and the second alert rex

Answer (score 0):

In

Dog.prototype = new Animal();

You are executing Animal() without parameters. And its OK for simulate inheritance in javascript.